# Convert SQL table to Document Store JSON

Tags: sql, json, nosql

I'm using document store NOSQL database RaptorDB to convert a relational database to document store in JSON schema. The sample "Library" database contains three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Book(
Book_Id int,
Author varchar(255),
Title varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (Book_Id)
)

CREATE TABLE Reader(
Reader_Id int,
Name varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (Reader_Id)
)

CREATE TABLE BookLending(
Reader_Id int,
Book_Id int,
ReturnDate DateTime,
FOREIGN KEY (Reader_Id) REFERENCES Reader(Reader_Id)
FOREIGN KEY (Book_Id) REFERENCES Book(Book_Id)
)
```

I wonder how is it possible to transform it to jSON format considering foreign keys.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Book, Reader and BookLending Documents:

`{ -id <objectid1>
    Author: “Khaled Hosseini”
    Title: “A Thousand Splendid Suns”
}
{ -id <objectid2>
    Name: “John Smith”
}
{ -id <objectid3>
    ReturnDate: “12-08-15”
    Reader_Id : <objectid2>
    Book_Id :<objectid1>
}`

Library Document – Denormalized data model:

`{ -id <objectid1>
    Author: “Edward P. Jones”
    Title: “The Known World”
    Reader: { Name: “John Smith”}
    BookLending: {ReturnDate: “24-07-15”}
}`

Data model:

`public class Library
    {
        public Library ()
        {
            ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
          public Guid ID { get; set; }
          public string Author { get; set; }
          public string Title { get; set; }
          public string Reader { get; set; }
          public datetime ReturnDate { get; set; }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check out the differences between sql and no-sql. You expect both to work in the same way, and there are a lot of differences between them, starting by the foreign keys.

I think your question is too ambiguous, because there is no exact mapping between these two concepts.

Comment: Yes, the question is a bit vague. Maybe it was better to ask how to map the document store schema to my data model.